# Creating multiple project within the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm still studying ASP.NET and for the project, I was trying to do a survey system.

So in this solution, there should be two projects with reference to the same model and the database.

One project is customer view and there's only loading the customer survey.

So to create this project I have already created models and the datasets.

The second project is the Admin view for the customer responses.

This project also reading data from the same dataset as the project one.

So I want to know how to create this second project within the same solution referring to the same database. Can you guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need more than two projects. All the common code should go into one or more projects that build to a library, i.e. DLL. Your two application projects can then both reference library project(s) and both make use of that common code. This is one reason that pretty much all decent sized projects should be broken up into parts from the start. You can then use the less specific parts elsewhere if required.

Comment: You mean like an API? Is there any tutorial for this kind of project? The first part ( customer form) is already completed. So there I create the database (I'm using EF) and the models and the datasets. So For the second project, I want to access the same to generate reports.

Comment: No I don't mean an API. I mean what I said. Just create a library project and reference it in the application project. Stop trying to make things harder than they are. You write code in a library in exactly the same way as you write code in an application. You reference libraries all the time - the entire .NET Framework is contained in libraries - so you already know everything you need to know.